# Has vs Had: grammar usage

Tags: word-choice, tense

Context of the sentence: One day, my dog ran away and couldn't be found.

'A week later, a letter came from my aunt saying that the dog **has** returned.'

Is it grammatically correct to use has or had?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you think that there is a problem.  What principle or rule are you using?

Comment: The situation you are talking about is in the past, so use the past tense.

Comment: @JamesK So are you saying the original sentence is correct in using 'has'?

Comment: I'm saying that you need to complete your question.  You have a doubt about this sentence. Why do you doubt it? Explain what you think.  You could start with "I think is should be 'has' because..."  or "... it should be 'has' because" or "...both are correct because..."